# Obscure C construct on interlaced switch

Tags: c, syntax, switch-statement, do-while

I came across this syntax on the Wikipedia page on `Duff's Device`.
The page mentions, that such construct helps with some modulo-divide requirement in this case, particularly 8, as here:

```
send(to, from, count)
register short *to, *from;
register count;
{
    register n = (count + 7) / 8;
    switch (count % 8) {
    case 0: do { *to = *from++;
    case 7:      *to = *from++;
    case 6:      *to = *from++;
    case 5:      *to = *from++;
    case 4:      *to = *from++;    /* {int somevar =0;} */
    case 3:      *to = *from++;
    case 2:      *to = *from++;
    case 1:      *to = *from++;
            } while (--n > 0);
    }
}
```

How does control even reach `case 5` when the primary loop block is at `case 0`?
How is it syntactically correct? Also, why then is variable declaration inside the case statements constrained to block scope only?

**[Edit]**

Quoting lines from the same page, "...the first edition of The C Programming Language which requires only that the body of the switch be a syntactically valid (compound) statement within which case labels can appear prefixing any sub-statement...".

I believe that's an answer, however, why did the masters chose to do it thus?

Comment: Isn't the explanation [in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) enough to describe how it works? And the *comment* isn't in Wikipedia, so where did you copy this snippet from?

Comment: I added it, for the second part of my question.

Comment: Because they weren't "masters", they were pioneers. There's a whole lot of difference there. The person who built the first house isn't per definition the best builder in history. K&R were pretty clueless about proper program design in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That idiom is known as [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device), and depends on the fact that `switch/case` is a *very* thin abstraction over `goto`.

In C, it is permissible to jump from outside to inside a block like that (though a good compiler will warn if doing so will miss any variable initialisations).

Comment: Very insightful, and great answer.:)